# По радио играют/играет «The Smiths»

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Подскажите, будьте добры: по радио игра**ю**т или игра**е**т "the Smiths"?

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку "The Smiths" - это множественное число, то правильно - "**играют**".

Или **играет** группа "The Smiths".

Answer (score 1):

Я, пожалуй, не вижу причин спорить с тем, что "играют" — вариант просторечный. В официальном документе так, ясное дело, не пишут. Но в художественной литературе и разговорной речи эта конструкция будет чувствовать себя комфортно. Она уместна и как передача прямой речи и как стилизация авторского языка.

В конце концов, мы же можем сказать, что по радио поёт Леонтьев? Вот и когда кто-то играет по радио, ясно, о чём речь (ср. по телевизору выступил Горбачёв).

Так "играют" или "играет"? Можно и так, и эдак. Проблемы нет. Я объясню. Мы можем рассматривать группу и как совокупность участников, и как одну единицу,  потому повествовать о ней по-разному. Вопрос лишь в том, насколько хорошо это ложится в фразу. Играет "Машина времени" — да, играет "Песняры" — нет. Играет "Поющие сердца" — нет, играют "Поющие сердца" — да.

Если получается криво, нужно добавить, помимо названия, промежуточное слово или связку слов, указывающих на сущность явления: играют музыканты группы "Синяя птица".

В случае английских слов нет никакой критичности, потому что фраза с иностранным названием не звучит криво. Без разницы, играют "Битлз" или играет "Битлз". Вот если бы сказали "битлы", тогда да — только "играют".

"The Smiths" — это в русском не множественное число, а название. Подразумевать под ним мы в равной степени имеем право хоть музыкантов, хоть группу. В корне не соглашусь, что единственный правильный вариант "играют". Просто поставьте на место названия "Black Sabbath" или "Enigma" и вы в этом убедитесь.

Так что здесь хозяин — барин. Иностранную грамматику к русской лепить не нужно. Ради точности всегда можно добавить определяющее "группа" или "музыканты группы", но это формализм и избыточность, для имитации живой речи эти способы вредны.

Answer (score 0):

***По радио передают (музыку) "the Smiths".***
Другого я тут не вижу.

Играть можно по нотам. Или по переписке - в шахматы. А как играть по радио?!
И как вы вообще это понимаете? Бог с ними, Смитами, давайте что-нибудь из более близких примеров. 
*По радио играют "Песняры"?!* *По радио играет "Ласковый май"?!* Нет, это просторечие.
Думаю, неразрешимим противоречием в грамматике между неопределенно-личной конструкцией  (тот, кто "играет по радио" не может быть субъектом) и восприятием её определенно-личной (играет - кто?) и вызваны ваши затруднения.